# Display a message if a button isn't clicked for a certain period of time

Tags: jquery, html, css

How could I display a message after checking if a specific button wasn't clicked within a period of time (i.e. 20 seconds) using `jQuery`?

I already have a functional example which displays a message if the mouse stays idle after 30 seconds right [here](http://dev.kyleboyd.co.uk/SocialContainer/)

Thanks,
Kyle

Comment: Well, if the button takes you to another page... it must not have been clicked when the message appears, right?

Answer (score 1):

When you start the timeout, assign the ID it returns to a var:

```
function visible_a_message(){
  $('#warningMessage').show();
}
var timeout = 20000; //20 secs
var showWarningBox = setTimeout(visible_a_message, timeout);
```

Then when the button is clicked, clear that timeout:

```
<input type='button' onClick='clearTimeout(showWarningBox);'" />
```

This does not rely on the assumption that the button will take the user to a different page (it *does* cancel showing the message after the button has been clicked, no matter what the browser is doing) and it skips the cruft of using classes as variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
  var pageLoaded = new Date();

  $("#preventButton").click(function () {
    // mark as clicked only within 20 seconds after page load
    if (new Date() - pageLoaded <= 20000) {
      $(this).addClass("clicked");
    }
  });

  setTimeout(function conditionalMessage() {
    // show a message if #preventButton had not been marked as clicked
    if ( !$("#preventButton").is(".clicked") ) {
      alert("a message appears");
    }
  }, 30000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

from your page source I would use something like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#idletimeout").slideDown(); // show the warning bar
  },20000 //20 seconds
)
```

so whenever user do on that page he will see warning box unless he clicks on the button (leave the page actually)